# Check the generic type of object retrieved from a list

Tags: java, generics

I have the below member.

```
 protected List<FieldHandler> fieldHandlers;
```

This list contains a list of concrete fieldHandler objects. Below is how values are added to this list.

```
 fieldHandlers.add(new StringFieldHandler(fieldName));
```

Below is the FieldHandler object and a concrete implementation example.

```
public interface FieldHandler<T,R> {

R handle(R target, T fieldValue) throws JSONMapperException;
}


 public class IntegerFieldHandler extends ValueFieldHandler<Integer,JSONObject> {

public IntegerFieldHandler(String fieldName) {
    super(fieldName);
}

@Override
public JSONObject handle(JSONObject target, Integer fieldValue) throws JSONMapperException {
    try {
        target.put(fieldName, fieldValue);
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        throw new JSONMapperException(ex);
        //log the exception
    }
    return target;
}
```

}

Now I'm trying to get values from this list. Which could eventually be StringFieldHandlers or IntegerFieldHandlers or BooleanFieldHandlers.

```
FieldHandler fieldHandlerForCurrentHBaseColumnValue = fieldHandlers.get(i);
```

I need to check which handler this is and call the relevant handle method passing in the value.

I tried doing it this way but it seems ugly.

```
JSONObject targetObject = null;
FieldHandler fieldHandlerForCurrentHBaseColumnValue = fieldHandlers.get(i);
if (fieldHandlerForCurrentHBaseColumnValue instanceof IntegerFieldHandler) {
     IntegerFieldHandler integerFieldHandler = (IntegerFieldHandler) fieldHandlerForCurrentHBaseColumnValue;
     targetObject =      integerFieldHandler.handle(targetObject,(Integer) tuple.get(i));
} else if (fieldHandlerForCurrentHBaseColumnValue instanceof BooleanFieldHandler) {

} else if (fieldHandlerForCurrentHBaseColumnValue instanceof StringFieldHandler) {

}
```

How can I do this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `getClass()`, `instance of ` can work

Comment: Edited the question with what I tried :)

Comment: You have to cast the variable to the type after checking with `instanceof`. This check is usually a red flag, though, that you are using the wrong class structure. Try using a factory pattern, or an overloaded method.

Comment: I don't see why you need to do this. They all implement the same interface and so the compile time type's method will be called; just call it.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils don't I need to cast the second parameter to Integer,String or boolean according to what I get from the list?

Comment: How are you actually using this; is the value known or do you force some random value for whatever handler you have? Checking the `instanceof` the handler seemed odd since polymorphism can determine which method implementation is called.

Comment: values are coming from HBase database. So I iterate the list of values inside the tuples and call each handler according to its data type. So the values are of type "Object".

Comment: So it's a fact that *i* matches such that you know for a *fact* that the *i-th* type is handled by the *i-th* handler?

Comment: yes exactly! i know which handler to call based on "i-th" type